# How to use variable instead of packet["source_addr_long"]

Tags: python, xbee

I am bhushan . I am new to python programming .

I have programmed xbee in API Mode .

End Device1 --> Router1 --> Coordinator .
End Device2 --> Router2 --> Coordinator .

Coordinator need to select either router 1  or router 2 to reply

```
  xbee1.tx(frame='0x1'
           , dest_addr=packet["source_addr"] 
           , data='Hi' 
           , dest_addr_long=packet["source_addr_long"]
          )  # It Works.
```

I want to use either address of router1 or router2 instead of packet["source_addr_long"]. decision has to be taken at runtime .

How can i store and retrieve address   ?

```
 print source_addr_long1
```

output -- \x00\x13\xa2\x00\x40\xb5\xad\x6e

```
 print  b"".join( byte for byte  in  source_addr_long1 )
```

output -- \x00\x13\xa2\x00\x40\xb5\xad\x6e

```
 print  b"".join( byte for byte  in  "\x00\x13\xa2\x00\x40\xb5\xad\x6e")
```

output -- Non Printable code

```
 destaddr = "\x00\x13\xa2\x00\x40\xb5\xad\x6e"
 xbee1.tx(frame='0x1'
           , dest_addr=packet["source_addr"] 
           , data='Hi' 
           , dest_addr_long=destaddr 
          )  # It Work.
```

When i use string it gives me error

```
 xbee1.tx(frame='0x1' ,
          dest_addr=source_addr1 ,
          data='Hi' , 
          dest_addr_long=source_addr_long1
          ) # Not Works



     xbee1.tx(frame='0x1' , dest_addr=source_addr1 , data='Hi' ,   dest_addr_long=source_addr_long1) # Not Works
   File "I:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xbee\base.py", line 418, in <lambda>
return lambda **kwargs: self.send(name, **kwargs)
   File "I:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xbee\base.py", line 386, in send
self._write(self._build_command(cmd, **kwargs))
   File "I:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xbee\base.py", line 195, in _build_command
% (field['name'], field['len']))
 ValueError: The data provided for 'dest_addr_long' was not 8 bytes long
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the answer .

I was having following scenario .

```
  source_addr  = ['0x8f', '0x18']

  source_addr_long =  ['0x00', '0x13', '0xa2', '0x00', '0x40', '0xb5', '0xad', '0x6e']


 # Coordinator transmit packet to any router .
 # Decision  can be taken at run time by  coordinator.
 # One to many nodes transmission is thus possible.

 xbee1.tx(
   frame='0x1' 
 , dest_addr=bytearray( int(x,16) for  x in source_addr)
 , data='Hi' 
 , dest_addr_long= bytearray( int(x,16) for  x in source_addr_long)
```

)

```
# It Works .
#  hex(19) => '0x13'
#  int('0x13',16)  => 19

#  x = '0x13' 
# then int(x,16) will be 19
```